# Writing a Closed form expression Discrete maths

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

$$∑_{i=1}^n a_i=n^2-n$$
Write a closed form expression for $$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$$ in terms of n and then simplify.

Hello, Just asking this question to see if this answer is right.
I'm still not 100% sure about these types of questions. This is what I've gotten.

$$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 +...+n+n-1...(1)$$ 
$$∑_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1+ a_2 + a_3+...+n ...(2)$$
Sub (1) into (2)
$$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i = ∑_{i=1}^n a_i + n-1$$
we know that (1) = $n^2-n$
therefore $$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i = n^2 -n + n-1$$
and simplified that is $n^2 -1$

I'm not sure about the n+ n-1 part and that seems to be a big factor in whether this question is right. any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = a_1 + a_2 +...+ n + (n-1)$ instead of $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = a_1 + a_2 +...+ (n-2) + (n-1)$? Am I missing something?

Comment: More to the point: why n instead of a_n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** (not intended to be a complete solution): Let $$f(n) \equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i = n^2 - n\text{.}$$
**Notice that the above is a function of $n$**. What is $f(n-1)$?

Comment: f(n-1) = (n-1)^2 - (n-1)

Comment: @user3491814 Now simplify that, and you're done.

Comment: oh wow I didn't think it could be that simple. so my attempt above is completely wrong?

Comment: @user3491814 The only thing wrong with your attempt above is that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + \boxed{a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}}$$
for example (notice the boxed portion). I think it's easier to just realize that what you're looking at with $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$$ is just a function of $n$.

Comment: ok so say that i=0 and we have $a_0 = 4$ would that be (n-1)^2 -(n-1) + 4?

Comment: @user3491814 No, since $i \geq 1$, since you have $i=1$ as the base of the summation.

Comment: Right but I've got the same question as above but the base summation is $i=0$, and its stated that $a_0 = 4 $ so $$∑_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i$$  since we know what $$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i $$ is equal to, we just add the value for $i=0$ which is $a_0 = 4$

Comment: @user3491814 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not explicitly stated that
$∑_{i=1}^n a_i=n^2-n$
for *all* $n$.
It might just be true for
one particular value of $n$.

In this case,
there is absolutely *nothing*
that can be deduced about
$∑_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$.

Do I get the
quibbler of the year award?